# windows 8 listbox selection color

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have styled listbox in WPF written in Win7
So my style is

```
<ListBox>
 <ListBox.Resources>
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#3399FF" />
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="#000000" />
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="#3399FF" />
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="#000000" />
 </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

This code makes same selection of listbox item in focused and defocused state. When I run my program under Windows 8 this appearance didn't work.
Where is an error in my code?

Comment: `InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey` and `InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey` aren't available in Windows 7/.NET 4.

Answer (score 3):

`ListBoxItem` in Windows-8 seems to have

```
<MultiTrigger>
  <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
  </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
  <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
</MultiTrigger>
```

for it's inactive selection Trigger in the default Style which then uses `SystemColors.ControlBrushKey` and `SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey` so you might want to override them too in your resources,

Maybe something like:

```
<ListBox>
 <ListBox.Resources>
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#3399FF" />
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="#000000" />
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="#3399FF" />
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="#000000" />
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="#3399FF" />
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="#000000" />
 </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

or just create a `Style` yourself(base it on the default template) and set the colors directly on this new `Style` which would then be guaranteed to apply on any version of the OS and you don't have to keep backtracking and checking if something has changed in defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ItemTemplate as:

```
 <ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label  Margin="-5, -2,-5,-2" Content="{Binding Item}">
                            <Label.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Label">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}},Path=IsFocused}" Value="False"/>
                                                <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},Path=IsSelected}" Value="True"/>
                                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="CornflowerBlue"/>
                                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},Path=IsSelected}" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Label.Style>
                        </Label>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```